# MYSQL Group_Concat values into one field but keep multiple rows

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have two tables in MySQL, one containing a single value in each row and the other containing the same values, but they are all combined into a single row. So for example:

Table1:

```
Column1
a
b
```

Table2:

```
Column1
a,b
```

I would like to make a mapping table based off of table 1 so that I can do a join on them.  The result I am looking for would be this:

```
Column1 |  Column2
a       |  a,b
b       |  a,b
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT Column1, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Column1) AS Column2 
FROM Table1
```

But it just returns a single row:

```
Column1 | Column2
a       | a,b
```

I have also tried adding a group by clause:

```
SELECT Column1, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Column1) AS Column2 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Column1
```

This returns each row, but doesn't concatenate the fields into column2:

```
Column1 | Column2
a       | a
b       | b
```

Is there any way to solve this?  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the table with a subquery that returns the concatenated value.

```
SELECT t1.Column1, g.c
FROM Table1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Column1) AS c
    FROM Table1) AS g
```

Comment: This did the trick! I had tried subqueries, but I was not aware of the CROSS JOIN. Thanks!